# What is the conventional notation for a function that returns 2 dissimilar items?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, notation

I see similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719434/notation-for-multiple-function-outputs) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328808/notation-for-a-function-with-multiple-return-values) but they do not answer my question.

The backstory is a little complicated but short version is I have a function $f(\cdots)$ that effectively returns 2 dissimilar results, a scalar $x$ and a vector $\mathbf{y}$.  I do *not* mean there are multiple possible solutions as in e.g. polynomial root solving.  I mean $f(\cdots)$ produces $x$ and if you have $x$ you have a unique value for $\mathbf{y}$.  The long way to write this out would be
$$ x=f(\cdots) \\ \mathbf{y}=g(x,\cdots)$$
but I don't want to break this out into 2 stages and I do not want to stack them into a vector like this
$$ \begin{bmatrix}x\\\mathbf{y} \end{bmatrix}=f(\cdots). $$
I would like something like
$$ x,\mathbf{y}=f(\cdots) $$
to denote that $x$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are a matched set.

Is there common notation to convey this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the problem with the vector notation?

Personally, I would define $f$ to produce a 2-tuple $(x, \mathbf{y})$. Unfortunately this is essentially the same as the "vector notation". If you want $f$ to produce $x$ and $\mathbf{y}$ where $x\neq\mathbf{y}$, with the same input, then $f$ is not a function (it is not well-defined!).

Comment: There's no _problem_ with vector notation. For what I am doing, I would like to keep the two entities distinct and lumping them into one vector goes against that.  Tuples may be what I am looking for.  Not sure we're on the same page about $f$ not being well defined.  Example: $(x,\mathbf{y})=(t,[2t\,3t]^T)(t)$.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory In your example, the function is returning a single tuple of a scalar and a vector, not the impossible "two different things simultaneously" IAAW was alluding to.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory If you're worried about commas separating $x$ from $\mathbf{y}$ and also entries of $\mathbf{y}$ from each other, semicolons are sometimes used to separate such entries in tuples (so like $(t; 2t, 3t)$).

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn No, commas aren't a problem.  In fact, a mix of commas and semicolons has a specific meaning in what I'm working on.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory a 2-tuple is one object, just like a vector. They are interchangeable. For example, the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ can have vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ or of the form $(a, b)$.

Comment: @IAAW Yes. I don't want to use a vector.  Nothing else in the context of what I am doing uses vectors that have mixed element types.  I want notation that is different and clear for a single case of a function that spits out 2 values of dissimilar type.

Comment: I understand. What I'm trying to communicate is that you can't do that. A function can't produce two distinct values, otherwise it's not a function. That's what "well-defined" means: exactly one input from the domain corresponds to exactly one output from the codomain. Your other option is to have your function produce one value which contains both of the outputs you want, which is a 2-tuple (equivalently, the vector).

Comment: @IAAW Having my function produce one value which contains both of the outputs is what I'm talking about.  I tried to make this clear in my question but evidently I failed.  2-tuple is good, vector bad for fluffy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like a pair as in $f(t)=(x(t), \mathbf y(t))$, then you could separate the two functions but relate them with a diacritic or other typographic distinction. For example, maybe $f(t)$ is a scalar and $\widetilde{\mathbf f}(t)$ is a related vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need both $x$ and $\mathbf{y}$ to fall out of the one thing.

Answer (score 1):

$\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}$First and foremost, a function is a *relation*:  a collection $R$ of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ is an element of some domain $D$, and $y$ is an element of some codomain $E$.  In more concise notation,
$$ R \subseteq D\times E. $$
A *function* $f$ is a special kind of relation which has the property that
$$ (x,y_1), (x,y_2) \in f \implies y_1 = y_2. $$
In particular, this implies that a function $f$ is a collection of ordered pairs.  From the point of view of notation, it doesn't really matter *what* the domain and codomain are.  The notation
$$ y = f(x) $$
means that the ordered pair $(x,y) \in f$, where $x \in D$ (i.e. $x$ is in the domain of $f$), and $y \in E$ (i.e $y$ is in the codomain of $f$).  This notation is perfectly fine for whatever domain and codomain $f$ might have—the notation doesn't care if $y$ is a number; or a vector; or a fish; or a tuple which contains a number, a vector, and a fish.

From the question, it sounds like the intended idea is that there is a function $f$ which takes some input $t$, then produces two objects as output:  a scalar $s(t)$ and a vector $\vec{v}(t)$.  I would suggest that the notation
$$ f : D \to k \times V : t \mapsto \bigl( s(t), \vec{v}(t) \bigr)$$
would be reasonable, where $D$ is the domain of $f$, $k$ is the field of scalars, and $V$ is a vector space (presumably over $k$, but the question is not clear about this).  In other words, I would write
$$ f(t) = (s, \vec{v}) = \bigl( s(t), \vec{v}(t) \bigr), $$
where $t \in D$ is some input, $s = s(t) \in k$ is a scalar, and $\vec{v} = \vec{v}(t)$ is a vector.